# how to insert data into SQLite using ionic

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic.I want to add data into SQLite which is coming from remote server. I have successfully populated data into list.so how can i store this data into sqlite. here is my code. how do i pass this data to query.I am unable to do this.

service.js

```
angular.module('starter.service',[]).
  factory('userServices',['$http',function($http){
    var users = [];

    return {
      get: function(){
        return $http.get("http://xxxxxxxxx-info").then(function(response){
          users = response.data;

          return users;

        });
      },
      remove:function(content){
        users.splice(users.indexOf(content),1);
      },
      getUser:function(chatId)
      {
        for(var i=0; i<users.length;i++){
          if(users[i].content_id === parseInt(chatId)){
            return users[i];

          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
  }]);
```

controller.js

```
 angular.module('shoppingPad.controller', [])


      .controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, userServices, $ionicModal, $cordovaSQLite) {
        console.log('inside controller');
       userServices.get().then(function (users) {
          //users is an array of user objects
          $scope.contents = users;
          console.log($scope.contents);
          var query = "INSERT INTO content (content_id, display_name) VALUES (?,?)";
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [users.content_id, users.display_name]).then(function (res) {
            alert(res);
            alert('Inserted');
          }, function (e) {
            alert('Error:' + e.message);
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define db? It's necessary to wait until device is ready.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });

    // just first time you need to define content table
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE content (content_id integer, display_name text)");

    userServices.get().then(function (users) {
          //users is an array of user objects
          $scope.contents = users;
          console.log($scope.contents);
          var query = "INSERT INTO content (content_id, display_name) VALUES (?,?)";
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [users.content_id, users.display_name]).then(function (res) {
            alert(res);
            alert('Inserted');
          }, function (e) {
            alert('Error:' + e.message);
          });
    });
});
```

Are you sure, that your object users look like

```
{
     "content_id":12,
     "display_name":"hello world"
}
```

and not like

```
  [
    {
         "content_id":12,
         "display_name":"hello world"
    },
    {
         "content_id":13,
         "display_name":"stackoverflow"
    },
    ...
]
```

I just ask, because `users` sounds like more than one entry.

Comment: It contain multiple entries

Comment: Then you must loop over every single item and add them one by one to the database